# Variable overwritten when using asynchronous AJAX (using jQuery) request to load data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, asynchronous

I have the following code that loads information about a users payments a month in advance of when it's needed. The function works when I wait for each month to load however it fails when multiple ajax requests are being run. Basically duplicate data gets added to my monthData array which implies that loadedPaymentMonth is being overwritten each function call. I'd like to load the data asynchronously so any thoughts?

This doesn't work:

```
var monthData=[]; 
function loadMonth(monthToLoad,curMonth){
    $("#paymentContent").find(".loader").remove();
    var monthToGet;
    switch(monthToLoad){
        case "Next": monthToGet=monthData.length-curMonth+1;
        break;
        case "Prev": monthToGet=-curMonth-1;
        break;
        case "This": monthToGet=currentMonthPointer-curMonth;
        break;
    }
    var loadedPaymentMonth=new PaymentMonth();
    if(monthToGet<0){
        currentMonthPointer+=1;
        monthData.unshift(loadedPaymentMonth);
    }
    else{
        monthData.push(loadedPaymentMonth);
    }
    $.getJSON(host+"GetDataForMonth.aspx?StartMonth="+monthToGet,function(data){
        loadedPaymentMonth.setMonthData(data.monthData,data.month,data.year);
        if($("#paymentsContent").find(".loader").remove().length>0){
            loadedPaymentMonth.createPaymentRowsForMonth();
        }
    }).error(function(){
        $("#paymentsContent").find(".loader").remove();
    });
}
```

This does:

```
function loadMonth(monthToLoad,curMonth){
    $("#paymentContent").find(".loader").remove();
    var monthToGet;
    switch(monthToLoad){
        case "Next": monthToGet=monthData.length-curMonth+1;
        break;
        case "Prev": monthToGet=-curMonth-1;
        break;
        case "This": monthToGet=currentMonthPointer-curMonth;
        break;
    }
    var loadedPaymentMonth=new PaymentMonth();
    if(monthToGet<0){
        currentMonthPointer+=1;
        monthData.unshift(loadedPaymentMonth);
    }
    else{
        monthData.push(loadedPaymentMonth);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url:host+"GetDataForMonth.aspx?StartMonth="+monthToGet,
        async:false,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
        loadedPaymentMonth.setMonthData(data.monthData,data.month,data.year);
        if($("#paymentsContent").find(".loader").remove().length>0){
            loadedPaymentMonth.createPaymentRowsForMonth();
        }
        }
    }).error(function(){
        $("#paymentsContent").find(".loader").remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: var loadedPaymentMonth=new PaymentMonth(); creates a new PaymentMonth object and inserts it into an array. Each function call should create a new paymentmonth object. So while the variable name might be the same, the reference should be specific to the function context it was created in.

Answer (score 0):

So I had code that checked to see if a month had loaded and if not, it loaded it. However, I was not handling the case for this instance. Because the paymentmonth is added before the AJAX starts, I needed to replace the old paymentmonth object with a new one (just using the old paymentmonth object can also cause synch issues if the new request completes before the old). So this:

```
if(monthToGet<0){
    currentMonthPointer+=1;
    monthData.unshift(loadedPaymentMonth);
}
else{
    monthData.push(loadedPaymentMonth);
}
```

Became this:

```
var loadedPaymentMonth=new PaymentMonth();
if(monthToLoad!="This"){
    if(monthToGet<0){
        currentMonthPointer+=1;
        monthData.unshift(loadedPaymentMonth);
    }
    else{
        monthData.push(loadedPaymentMonth);
    }
}
else{
    monthData[currentMonthPointer]=loadedPaymentMonth;
}
```